# Tikz Graph Drawing Layered Optimization

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to do a layered graph with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, quotes}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            font=\small,
            every node/.style = draw,
            rounded corners,
            sibling distance = 0.85cm
        }
        \graph [layered layout]
        {
            { [edge={draw=none}] "1950er" -- "1960er" -- "1970er" -- "1980er" -- "1990er" -- "2000er" -- "2010er"};
            { [same layer] "1950er", "COBOL", "FORTRAN"};
            { [same layer] "1960er", "ALGOL", "LISP", "Simula" };
            { [same layer] "1970er", "PASCAL", "Smalltalk", "C"};
            { [same layer] "1980er", "Objective C", "ADA", "Eiffel", "Object PASCAL", "Erlang", "C++" };
            { [same layer] "1990er", "JAVA" [blue], "Object COBOL", "Python" };
            { [same layer] "2000er", "Scala", "C\#" };
            { [same layer] "2010er", "Dart", "Rust", "Kotlin", "Go"};

            "ALGOL" -- {
                "C" -- {
                    "C++" -- "JAVA" -- {
                        "C\#",
                        "Scala",
                        "Kotlin",
                        "Dart"
                    },
                    "Objective C",
                    "Python",
                    "Go",
                    "Dart"
                }, 
                "PASCAL" -- {
                    "Object PASCAL",
                    "Go"
                },
                "Simula" -- {
                    "C++" -- {
                        "C\#" -- {
                            "Dart",
                            "Rust",
                            "Kotlin"
                        },
                        "Rust",
                        "Dart"
                    },
                    "Smalltalk" -- {
                        "Eiffel",
                        "JAVA",
                        "Objective C",
                        "Object PASCAL",
                        "Object COBOL",
                        "Dart",
                        "Erlang"
                    },
                    "Eiffel" -- "Kotlin"
                },
                "ADA" -- "Python"
            };

            "LISP" -- {
                "Smalltalk",
                "Erlang"
            };

            "COBOL" -- "Object COBOL"; 

            { [edge={draw=none}]
                "COBOL" -- "ALGOL",
                "ALGOL" -- "LISP"
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Layered Graph]

Is there a way to tune the auto-routing a bit, such that there is less overlap of edges and nodes.

Comment: I think what you're after is [Crossing Minimization](https://tikz.dev/gd-layered#sec-31.4). That said, it seems the order of declaration (in the `[same layer]`) defines the order of appearance. Maybe, some reordering there helps achieve a cleaner output, maybe even adding fake (nondrawn textless) nodes at some points? Of course, step-by-step this makes the usage of GD pointless

Comment: I don't think that the order defines it, see C++ is the last in the appearance. 

I Have seen the Crossing Minimisation, however, I don't understad how to set it. Even If I read Pohlmans Thesis, it is not clear to me. There also does not exists a comprehensive list of all possible algorithms that could be chosen.

Comment: Yeah, *define* is the wrong word. Maybe *initialize*? The manual's example has the same order in the code as in the output. I'm assuming some human reordering is necessary. I don't think the `=<string>` actually means anything. There's only one algorithm implemented and it is activated by default? All these Graph Drawing libraries are nice when they work but if they don't it's not easy to adjust it. :(

Comment: 4.3.5. looks like that more algorithms can be specified... and as you can see in my example, I did already the reordering, see C++... Its not there where it would be less harmful...

Comment: Hi!  Is the order on each row important?  For example, could the elements, say of the 1980s be permuted?

Comment: Sure, @DanielN, that's the only degree of freedom right? So it would be nice if they could be reordered such that the overlap is reduced to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

[image: diagram]

I used `matrix` library to have some control on the nodes' positions.  I also changed the order of nodes on some rows to disentangle the diagram.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (L) [matrix of nodes,
  column sep=3ex, row sep=5ex,
  nodes={%
    draw, rounded corners,
    inner sep=2ex, outer sep=.5ex,
    minimum width=10ex, minimum height=5ex
  },
  empty node/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
  every edge/.style={%
    draw, very thin, -,
    preaction={draw=white, -, line width=1ex}
  }]
  {%
    1950er &&&&&&&&&& |(cobol)| COBOL & FORTRAN \\
    1960er &&& |(simula)| Simula &&& |(algol)| Algol && |(lisp)| LISP  \\
    1970er &&&&& |(c)| C && |(smalltalk)| Smalltalk
    && |(pascal)| PASCAL \\
    1980er & |(eiffel)| Eiffel && |(oc)| Objective C
    && |(c++)| C++ &&&  |(opascal)| Object PASCAL
    && |(ada)| ADA && |(erlang)| Erlang \\
    1990er && |(java)[blue]| JAVA
    &&&&&& |(python)| Python &&& |(ocobol)| Object COBOL \\
    2000er && |(scala)| Scala & |(csharp)| C\# \\
    2010er & |(kotlin)| Kotlin &&& |(rust)| Rust &&& |(dart)| Dart
    && |(go)| Go \\
  };
  \path (cobol) edge (ocobol);
  
  \path (algol) edge (c) edge (pascal) edge (simula) edge (ada);
  \path (c) edge (c++) edge (oc) edge (python) edge (go) edge (dart);
  \path (pascal) edge (opascal) edge (go);
  \path (simula) edge (c++) edge (smalltalk) edge (eiffel);
  \path (ada) edge (python);

  \path (c++) edge (java) edge (csharp) edge (dart) edge (rust);
  \path (java) edge (csharp) edge (scala) edge (kotlin) edge (dart);
  \path (csharp) edge (rust) edge (kotlin) edge (dart);
  
  \path (simula) edge (c++) edge (smalltalk) edge (eiffel);
  \path (smalltalk) edge (eiffel) edge (java) edge (oc)
  edge (opascal) edge (ocobol) edge (dart) edge (erlang);
  \path (eiffel) edge (kotlin);

  \path (ada) edge (python);
  
  \path (lisp) edge (smalltalk) edge (erlang);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's nice, but not the really the answer to my question, I want to understand how a Graph Drawing (auto routing) can solve this.